# get all visible menu item for given user

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

in openerp(odoo) you can write URL directly and access any view even if user dosen't have access to it. My idea is to stop actions that has no visible menu for it. openerp do it somewhere but I don't know where and how to access the list of available menu for given user.

Thanks